# Help with custom getline() function

Tags: c, kr-c

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getline(int lim)
{
    char c;
    int i;
    char *line;
    line = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim);


    i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < lim-1)
    {
        *line = c;
        line++;
        i++;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    printf("%s", line);
    return line;
}
```

I'm not worried about the return value right now - just the reason as to why `printf("%s", line)` isn't working.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** fixed to `line = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim);` but it is still not working.

**Solution:** the address of `*line` was being incremented throughout the function. When it was passed to `printf()`, `*line` pointed to '\0' because that's where its adress was incremented to. Using a temprorary pointer that stored the original address allocated by `malloc()` to `*line` and then passing that pointer into `printf()`, allowed for the function to walk up the pointer.

Comment: sizeof char is 1 by definition, so this is redundant.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: True, but I think it should stay this way, since the current version is more explicit. The compiler will convert it all into a constant anyway.

Comment: Well, there is an argument for using sizeof *lim for robustness against future change, but using sizeof(char) is just a waste of typing (IMHO).

Comment: @Charles: I think you mean sizeof(*line)?

Comment: I like the sizeof(*line) option best. To each their own! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are only allocating enough space for a single character in this line:

```
line = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

And that is getting filled with the `\0` before your `printf` statement.

I'm guessing you want to change this line to:

```
/* Allocate enough room for 'lim' - 1 characters and a trailing \0 */
line = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim);
```

Or even better:

```
char *line, *tmp;
tmp = line = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim);
```

And then use `tmp` in all of your pointer math, this way `line` will still point to the start of your string.

And I know it's early in your development, but you'll want to make sure you `free()` the memory that you `malloc()`.

---

Here is a working version of your function including my suggested changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getline(int lim)
{
    char c;
    int i;
    char *line, *tmp;
    tmp = line = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim);

    i = 0;
    /* NOTE: 'i' is completely redundant as you can use 'tmp',
     * 'line,' and 'lim' to determine if you are going to
     * overflow your buffer */
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < lim-1)
    {
        *tmp = c;
        tmp++;
        i++;
    }
    *tmp = '\0';
    printf("%s", line);
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion helped me figure out that printf() and, I am assuming all, other functions that take a pointer as an argument work with what they get as they are passed -- they don't reset the pointer to the beginning of the allocated block.

Comment: I would have accepted and voted up your answer sooner (saving you the work of all that extra explaining, but I didn't have internet for the past three hours or so. Thanks again. That was very, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're printing a zero-length string.

```
*line = '\0';
printf("%s", line);
```

I presume that you want to store what `line` was originally (as returned from `malloc`) and print that.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have allocated enough room for only one character. Did you mean the following instead:

```
line = malloc(lim * sizeof(char));
```

Also, you don't want to change `line` after reading each character. Use the following block for your while-loop instead:

```
*(line + i) = c;
i++;
```

And finally, to null-terminate the string, use:

```
*(line + i) = '\0';
```

Comment: Or use line[i] instead of *(line + i) for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Updated-it was a simple typo mistake,but you didn't have to vote me down on it

instead of

```
     char *line= malloc(sizeof(char));
```

try

```
    int space= //number of how many characters you need on the line
    char *line= malloc(sizeof(char)*space);
```

sorry I meant

```
   char *line= malloc( sizeof(char)*lim)
```

Comment: "char *line= lim * sizeof(char)" -- Huh?

Comment: @TStamper: Your first suggestion will work, but the "space" variable is unneccessary. The function that Tyler describes has the "lim" argument for this purpose.

Comment: @TStamper: Your second suggestion is wrong. You perform a calculation, and then use the result as the memory location pointed to by "line".

Comment: I'm sorry about that, TStamper. I hadn't noticed the change, and SO didn't notify me of your comment. Downvote replaced with upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has covered these points already, but here is the whole thing all put together:

**Edit:** Improved the code a little

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getline(int lim)
{
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * lim); // allocate result buffer

    int i = 0;
    char c;
    char *line = result;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < lim-1)
    {
        *line = c;
        line++;
        i++;
    }
    *line = '\0';

    printf("%s", result); // print the result
    return result; // return the result buffer (remember to free() it later)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're also overwriting memory you don't own. You're malloc'ing one character, setting *line to c, and then incrementing line and repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of pointer, and how it's different from a buffer.
In your code, you treat "line" as pointer and buffer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are Making mistake on two points (but you can say same mistake or two ,its upto you). first your pointer should be incremented like

*(line+i) = c;
Due to this reason when you set the Null char at the end of loop you are actually saying the compiler to point the pointer to only this poistion.Hence the pointer is only pointing at Null String not the whole string. As it was constantly being moved in each step of the loop. 
 So when you tried to print that the pointer has nothing to print. So if you change your statement inside the loop for pointer and assign the value to an express address rather then actually moving the pointer then you problem will be solved.

Note. If you change that line then you also need to modify your Null terminator assignment like this;
   *(line+limit) = '\0';